# Apply filter on still video and save it using metal

Tags: ios, swift, video-processing, metal

I tried video filtering using AVVideoComposition and CIFilter and that's working fine. But the problem is that its taking to much time. I read many tutorial to apply filter on live video using Metal. But i haven't found any way to apply filter on still video and saving it.

Can one tell me how to do this thing using metal ?

Comment: Did you solve it by chance?

Comment: @RoiMulia not yet but i think this can be possible with ffmpeg.